# Binary classification using a very simple Neural Net with Qiskit and Pennylane

Tags: qiskit, programming, pennylane

I implemented a simple Neural Net with Pennylane and Qiskit for classifying two half moons: [notebook for two half moons (GitHub)](https://github.com/Sultanow/quantum/blob/main/halfmoons_ibm_qiskit.ipynb). It works somehow (not overwhelmingly by any means):

[image]

I tried running the program on a public quantum device (IBM) and found very quickly that it would take months, not days, to complete the training. For this reason I built a much simpler net (my hope is that one qubit is enough), which is supposed to solve the classification task: [notebook for linear classification (GitHub)](https://github.com/Sultanow/quantum/blob/main/linear_ibm_qiskit.ipynb). It should divide the classes using a straight line:

[image]

While the full notebook (a very small one) can be found on the above linked GitHub page, the following snipped is relevant:

```
# Convert quantum layer to keras
n_layers = 4
weight_shapes = {"weights": (n_layers, n_qubits)}
qlayer = qml.qnn.KerasLayer(qnode, weight_shapes, output_dim=n_qubits)

# Define classical layers
clayer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
clayer_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([clayer_1, qlayer, clayer_2])
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
fitting = model.fit(x, y_hot, epochs=4, batch_size=5, validation_split=0.25, verbose=2)
```

Possibly it is a very simple error, which causes the net is recognizing all input as one and the same class:

[image]

I would be very grateful for any hint that pushes me towards the proper direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is Catalina from Xanadu.

If you run [this tutorial](https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_qnn_module_tf.html) does it work for you? It only uses 2 qubits and uses the moons dataset too.

If the tutorial doesn't work then it's probably not a problem in your code but in the connection to the backend. Have you tried different IBM devices? Their errors and waiting times vary a lot so trying different ones can help.

Comment: Yes - I ran this model multiple times on different quantum computers (IBM devices). Even after several days he was processing epoch 1. I do not have connection problems with the backend, because I could see that the quantum device successfully performed increasingly many of my jobs. The devices have a long queue time, currently of the order of 15 minutes per circuit i.e. per datapoint. Thats why I am really try to simplyfy the classification problem using a much simpler net with less data points.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Hi Eldar,
For classification problems, you could also use a quantum computer in the way shown in the attached image.  It is a method called the Universal Quantum Classifier - please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/13285)

Comment: @Peter-Jan, I think the original post was an attempt to perform a binary classification by trying a 1 qubit hybrid quantum-classical net.  The subsequent answer by states that 2 qubits would work.  My answer for the question: how to indeed use just 1 qubit as a classifier?   I believe that was the intent of the original post.